# how do i update/refresh the values without exit the system in netbeans gui?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

There have the user details show in the menu after login.....but when i do modify in the details jframe click and back to menu is not refresh to the latest value and still remain the values after i login. How am i gonna to refresh the value without exit the program ? My program is work fine...juz the details after modified is not showing...need to exit the system and run again then the details will be updated...but its not refresh automatically without exit the program. Below is my code in login jframe.

```
    {
       try(Scanner RD = new Scanner(new FileReader("Users.txt"));)
    {
        while(RD.hasNext())
       {
         String line = RD.nextLine();
            StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(line,":");

            String pw = token.nextToken();
            String name = token.nextToken();
            double balance =  Double.parseDouble(token.nextToken());
            String email = token.nextToken();
            String region = token.nextToken();
            User user = new User();
            user.setpw(pw);
            user.setName(name);
            user.setBalance(balance);
            user.setEmail(email);
            user.setRegion(region);


            if (pw.equals(textPw.getText()) )
            {
                    Label1.setText("Login Success");

                    Menu cust = new Menu(user);
                    cust.setVisible(true);
                    this.dispose();
            }
            else
            {   
                    jLabel1.setText("Invalid Password. Please try again");
            }              
        }
    }           
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Password.");
    }  
    }
```

Below is the menu jframe

```
    public Menu(User user){
    this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    initComponents();

    Menu.user = user;
    nm.setText(Menu.user.getName());
    sb.setText(Double.toString(Menu.user.getBalance()));
    em.setText(Menu.user.getEmail());

}
```

this is the code where im modify my data from the txtfile...after that when click the update and back to menu , the details in menu are not update still remain the same as while login.

```
    public void UpdateBalance()
{
    try(Scanner reader = new Scanner(new FileReader("Users.txt"));)
    {
        while(reader.hasNext())
        {
            String[] temp = reader.nextLine().split(":");               
            {                    
                temp[2] = amount.getText();
            }

            try(PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("Users.temp", true));)
            {
                write.println(temp[0] + ":" + temp[1] + ":" + temp[2] + ":" + temp[3] + ":" + temp[4] + ":" + temp[5]);
            } catch(IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
            reader.close();
            File oldFile = new File("Users.txt");
            if(oldFile.delete())
            {

            }
            File newFile = new File("Users.temp");
            newFile.renameTo(oldFile);                                  
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Below is the button that click for back to menu

```
    Menu cust = new Menu(Menu.user);        
    cust.setVisible(true);
    this.dispose();
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Clean and build your project and check if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying you don't see the controls update after changing them, you need to add a call `revalidate()`.

Comment: In my condition, need how to use revalidate() ?